# Converting dataframe to XML in spark throws Null Pointer Exception in StaxXML while writing to file system

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, databricks, stax

I am reading an `xml` file using sparkSession based on a given `rowTag`. The resultant dataFrame obtained needs to be converted to `xml` file. Below is the code I am trying out:

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
val xmldf = sparkSession.read.format(SEAConstant.STR_IMPORT_SPARK_DATA_BRICK_XML)
      .option(SEAConstant.STR_ROW_TAG, "Employee").option("nullValue", "").load("demo.xml")
    val columnNames = xmldf.columns.toSeq
    val sdf = xmldf.select(columnNames.map(c => xmldf.col(c)): _*)
sdf.write.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rootTag", "Company")
      .option("rowTag", "Employee").save("Rel")
```

This is the `xml` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
  <Employee id="id47" masterRef="#id53" revision="" nomenclature="">
<ApplicationRef version="J.0" application="Teamcenter"></ApplicationRef>
<UserData id="id52">
<UserValue valueRef="#id4" value="" title="_CONFIG_CONTEXT"></UserValue></UserData></Employee>
<Employee id="id47" masterRef="#id53" revision="" nomenclature="">
<ApplicationRef version="B.0" application="Teamcenter"></ApplicationRef>
<UserData id="id63">
<UserValue valueRef="#id5" value="" title="_CONFIG_CONTEXT"></UserValue></UserData></Employee>
</Company>
```

The problem here is that if I try only 3 columns to create `sdf` above by handpicking any 3 columns from `xmldf`, it works fine and creates the `xml` file. But if I give all the columns, even though they are 2 or 3 in number, it fails with below error:

```
19/06/25 14:45:14 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.databricks.spark.xml.parsers.StaxXmlGenerator$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(StaxXmlGenerator.scala:131)
    at com.databricks.spark.xml.parsers.StaxXmlGenerator$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(StaxXmlGenerator.scala:129)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)
    at com.databricks.spark.xml.parsers.StaxXmlGenerator$.apply(StaxXmlGenerator.scala:129)
    at com.databricks.spark.xml.util.XmlFile$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(XmlFile.scala:108)
    at com.databricks.spark.xml.util.XmlFile$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(XmlFile.scala:96)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1414)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/06/25 14:45:14 ERROR SparkHadoopWriter: Task attempt_20190625144513_0012_m_000000_0 aborted.
19/06/25 14:45:14 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I looked up at various places but couldn't find solution for it. Also, using same `sdf` generated above, I am able to create `json` file successfully.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xmldf.write.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rootTag", "Company")
     .option("rowTag", "Employee").option("attributePrefix", "_Att")
     .option("valueTag","_VALUE").save("Rel")
```

Replace the corresponding statement in OP by the this. `StaxParser` is actually looking for these `attributePrefix` and `valueTag`, without which it throws `NPE`. I found this out while looking it at this [github link](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/issues/153)

Answer (score 1):

Your nullpointer exception is not valid...

with spark **2.20** and below xml dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-xml_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I saved the samedata and retrieved back successfully... like below

```
package com.examples

import java.io.File

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, SparkSession}

/**
  * Created by Ram Ghadiyaram
  */
object SparkXmlTest {
  org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.
    master("local")
      .appName(this.getClass.getName)
      .getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val str =
    """
        |<?xml version="1.0"?>
        |<Company>
        |  <Employee id="1">
        |      <Email>tp@xyz.com</Email>
        |      <UserData id="id32" type="AttributesInContext">
        |      <UserValue value="7in" title="Height"></UserValue>
        |      <UserValue value="23lb" title="Weight"></UserValue>
        |</UserData>
        |  </Employee>
        |  <Measures id="1">
        |      <Email>newdata@rty.com</Email>
        |      <UserData id="id32" type="SitesInContext">
        |</UserData>
        |  </Measures>
        |  <Employee id="2">
        |      <Email>tp@xyz.com</Email>
        |      <UserData id="id33" type="AttributesInContext">
        |      <UserValue value="7in" title="Height"></UserValue>
        |      <UserValue value="34lb" title="Weight"></UserValue>
        |</UserData>
        |  </Employee>
        |  <Measures id="2">
        |      <Email>nextrow@rty.com</Email>
        |      <UserData id="id35" type="SitesInContext">
        |</UserData>
        |  </Measures>
        |  <Employee id="3">
        |      <Email>tp@xyz.com</Email>
        |      <UserData id="id34" type="AttributesInContext">
        |      <UserValue value="7in" title="Height"></UserValue>
        |      <UserValue value="" title="Weight"></UserValue>
        |</UserData>
        |  </Employee>
        |</Company>
      """.stripMargin
    println("save to file ")

    val f = new File("xmltest.xml")
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f, str)


    val xmldf = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rootTag", "Company")
      .option("rowTag", "Employee")
      .option("nullValue", "")
      .load(f.getAbsolutePath)
    val columnNames = xmldf.columns.toSeq
    val sdf = xmldf.select(columnNames.map(c => xmldf.col(c)): _*)
    sdf.write.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rootTag", "Company")
      .option("rowTag", "Employee")
      .mode("overwrite")
      .save("/src/main/resources/Rel1")


    println("read back from saved file ....")
    val readbackdf = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rootTag", "Company")
      .option("rowTag", "Employee")
      .option("nullValue", "")
      .load("/src/main/resources/Rel1")
    readbackdf.show(false)
  }

}
```

Result :

```
save to file 
read back from saved file ....
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|Email     |UserData                                                                      |_id|
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|tp@xyz.com|[WrappedArray([null,Height,7in], [null,Weight,23lb]),id32,AttributesInContext]|1  |
|tp@xyz.com|[WrappedArray([null,Height,7in], [null,Weight,34lb]),id33,AttributesInContext]|2  |
|tp@xyz.com|[WrappedArray([null,Height,7in], [null,Weight,null]),id34,AttributesInContext]|3  |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
```

***Update : With the latest XML OP updated i tried and got the exception and fixed with below piece of code...***

---

```
.option("attributePrefix", "_Att")
      .option("valueTag", "_VALUE")
```

***Full set of options and description from databricks :***

```
This package allows reading XML files in local or distributed filesystem as Spark DataFrames. When reading files the API accepts several options:

path: Location of files. Similar to Spark can accept standard Hadoop globbing expressions.
rowTag: The row tag of your xml files to treat as a row. For example, in this xml   ..., the appropriate value would be book. Default is ROW. At the moment, rows containing self closing xml tags are not supported.
samplingRatio: Sampling ratio for inferring schema (0.0 ~ 1). Default is 1. Possible types are StructType, ArrayType, StringType, LongType, DoubleType, BooleanType, TimestampType and NullType, unless user provides a schema for this.
excludeAttribute : Whether you want to exclude attributes in elements or not. Default is false.
treatEmptyValuesAsNulls : (DEPRECATED: use nullValue set to "") Whether you want to treat whitespaces as a null value. Default is false
mode: The mode for dealing with corrupt records during parsing. Default is PERMISSIVE.
PERMISSIVE :
When it encounters a corrupted record, it sets all fields to null and puts the malformed string into a new field configured by columnNameOfCorruptRecord.
When it encounters a field of the wrong datatype, it sets the offending field to null.
DROPMALFORMED : ignores the whole corrupted records.
FAILFAST : throws an exception when it meets corrupted records.
inferSchema: if true, attempts to infer an appropriate type for each resulting DataFrame column, like a boolean, numeric or date type. If false, all resulting columns are of string type. Default is true.
columnNameOfCorruptRecord: The name of new field where malformed strings are stored. Default is _corrupt_record.
attributePrefix: The prefix for attributes so that we can differentiate attributes and elements. This will be the prefix for field names. Default is _.
valueTag: The tag used for the value when there are attributes in the element having no child. Default is _VALUE.
charset: Defaults to 'UTF-8' but can be set to other valid charset names
ignoreSurroundingSpaces: Defines whether or not surrounding whitespaces from values being read should be skipped. Default is false.
When writing files the API accepts several options:

path: Location to write files.
rowTag: The row tag of your xml files to treat as a row. For example, in this xml   ..., the appropriate value would be book. Default is ROW.
rootTag: The root tag of your xml files to treat as the root. For example, in this xml   ..., the appropriate value would be books. Default is ROWS.
nullValue: The value to write null value. Default is string null. When this is null, it does not write attributes and elements for fields.
attributePrefix: The prefix for attributes so that we can differentiating attributes and elements. This will be the prefix for field names. Default is _.
valueTag: The tag used for the value when there are attributes in the element having no child. Default is _VALUE.
compression: compression codec to use when saving to file. Should be the fully qualified name of a class implementing org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec or one of case-insensitive shorten names (bzip2, gzip, lz4, and snappy). Defaults to no compression when a codec is not specified.
Currently it supports the shortened name usage. You can use just xml instead of com.databricks.spark.xml.
```

---

***Full example here :***

```
package com.examples

import java.io.File

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, SparkSession}

/**
  * Created by Ram Ghadiyaram
  */
object SparkXmlTest {
  // org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.
      master("local")
      .appName(this.getClass.getName)
      .getOrCreate()
    //  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    //    val str =
    //    """
    //        |<?xml version="1.0"?>
    //        |<Company>
    //        |  <Employee id="1">
    //        |      <Email>tp@xyz.com</Email>
    //        |      <UserData id="id32" type="AttributesInContext">
    //        |      <UserValue value="7in" title="Height"></UserValue>
    //        |      <UserValue value="23lb" title="Weight"></UserValue>
    //        |</UserData>
    //        |  </Employee>
    //        |  <Measures id="1">
    //        |      <Email>newdata@rty.com</Email>
    //        |      <UserData id="id32" type="SitesInContext">
    //        |</UserData>
    //        |  </Measures>
    //        |  <Employee id="2">
    //        |      <Email>tp@xyz.com</Email>
    //        |      <UserData id="id33" type="AttributesInContext">
    //        |      <UserValue value="7in" title="Height"></UserValue>
    //        |      <UserValue value="34lb" title="Weight"></UserValue>
    //        |</UserData>
    //        |  </Employee>
    //        |  <Measures id="2">
    //        |      <Email>nextrow@rty.com</Email>
    //        |      <UserData id="id35" type="SitesInContext">
    //        |</UserData>
    //        |  </Measures>
    //        |  <Employee id="3">
    //        |      <Email>tp@xyz.com</Email>
    //        |      <UserData id="id34" type="AttributesInContext">
    //        |      <UserValue value="7in" title="Height"></UserValue>
    //        |      <UserValue value="" title="Weight"></UserValue>
    //        |</UserData>
    //        |  </Employee>
    //        |</Company>
    //      """.stripMargin
    val str =
    """
      |<Company>
      |  <Employee id="id47" masterRef="#id53" revision="" nomenclature="">
      |<ApplicationRef version="J.0" application="Teamcenter"></ApplicationRef>
      |<UserData id="id52">
      |<UserValue valueRef="#id4" value="" title="_CONFIG_CONTEXT"></UserValue></UserData></Employee>
      |<Employee id="id47" masterRef="#id53" revision="" nomenclature="">
      |<ApplicationRef version="B.0" application="Teamcenter"></ApplicationRef>
      |<UserData id="id63">
      |<UserValue valueRef="#id5" value="" title="_CONFIG_CONTEXT"></UserValue></UserData></Employee>
      |</Company>
    """.stripMargin
    println("save to file ")

    val f = new File("xmltest.xml")
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f, str)


    val xmldf = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rootTag", "Company")
      .option("rowTag", "Employee")
      .option("nullValue", "")
      .load(f.getAbsolutePath)
    val columnNames = xmldf.columns.toSeq
    val sdf = xmldf.select(columnNames.map(c => xmldf.col(c)): _*)
    sdf.write.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rootTag", "Company")
      .option("rowTag", "Employee")
      .option("attributePrefix", "_Att")
      .option("valueTag", "_VALUE")
      .mode("overwrite")
      .save("./src/main/resources/Rel1")


    println("read back from saved file ....")
    val readbackdf = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rootTag", "Company")
      .option("rowTag", "Employee")
      .option("nullValue", "")
      .load("./src/main/resources/Rel1")
    readbackdf.show(false)
  }
}
```

Result :

```
save to file 
read back from saved file ....
+-----------------+-------------------------------+----+----------+
|ApplicationRef   |UserData                       |_id |_masterRef|
+-----------------+-------------------------------+----+----------+
|[Teamcenter, J.0]|[[_CONFIG_CONTEXT, #id4], id52]|id47|#id53     |
|[Teamcenter, B.0]|[[_CONFIG_CONTEXT, #id5], id63]|id47|#id53     |
+-----------------+-------------------------------+----+----------+
```

Comment: Strange. I was getting same error and when I tried with other options, it worked. See my answer below. Which spark version are you using? I am using 2.3.1

Comment: 19/06/25 16:40:03 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.2.0

Comment: Update : 2.3.1 also i tried successfully. your NPE is not valid

Comment: can you try by removing `.mode` option

Comment: commented `// .mode("overwrite") ` no change in result

Comment: Strange. I am still getting this error if I remove the solution I provided.

Comment: Also, I am actually reading this `xml` from a file. Not by providing it as a string as you have. Do you think that  might be one of the catch here? Please let me know.

Comment: So I have changed the xml file now in the OP. Please try this file and you should surely get the error mentioned in the OP this time. Please let me know. And this resolves by the fix I mentioned below as well.

Comment: any ways you got it in working state right, I  have no time to test this again, hence forth please post full deails (re-producable thing) with versions of software dependencies. otherwise it will be puzzle for answerers.